# Remove item from list based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a struct like this:

```
public struct stuff
{
    public int ID;
    public int quan;
}
```

and want to to remove the product where `ID` is 1.
I'm trying this currently:

```
prods.Remove(new stuff{ prodID = 1});
```

and it's not working.

**THANKS TO ALL**

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Using linq:

```
prods.Remove( prods.Single( s => s.ID == 1 ) );
```

Maybe you even want to use `SingleOrDefault()` and check if the element exists at all ...

**EDIT:**
Since `stuff`  is a struct, `SingleOrDefault()` will not return null. But it will return *default( stuff )*, which will have an ID of 0. When you don't have an ID of 0 for your *normal* stuff-objects you can query for this ID:

```
var stuffToRemove = prods.SingleOrDefault( s => s.ID == 1 );
if( stuffToRemove.ID != 0 )
{
    prods.Remove( stuffToRemove );
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure Remove(null) throws an exception which rules out SingleOrDefault where it is.

Comment: @Graphain: I added an example for you

Comment: Or possibly more readable `if (stuffToRemove != default(stuff))`.

Answer (score 273):

If your collection type is a `List<stuff>`, then the best approach is probably the following:

```
prods.RemoveAll(s => s.ID == 1)
```

This only does one pass (iteration) over the list, so should be more efficient than other methods.

If your type is more generically an `ICollection<T>`, it might help to write a short extension method if you care about performance. If not, then you'd probably get away with using LINQ (calling `Where` or `Single`).

Comment: "Cannot"? Haha. Don't be pedantic. Even if the author is working with with an IList, RemoveAll is pretty trivial to implement.

Comment: what about type casting to list ((List<prod>) prods).RemoveAll(s => s.ID == 1)

Answer (score 9):

If you have LINQ:

```
var itemtoremove = prods.Where(item => item.ID == 1).First();
prods.Remove(itemtoremove)
```

Comment: You can put your `where` query as a parameter to First()

Comment: Or you can just replace `Where` with `First`

Answer (score 3):

```
prods.Remove(prods.Find(x => x.ID == 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for those, who want to remove it from the **database** with **Entity Framework**:

`prods.RemoveWhere(s => s.ID == 1);`

And the extension method itself:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LivaNova.NGPDM.Client.Services.Data.Extensions
{
    public static class DbSetExtensions
    {
        public static void RemoveWhere<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> entities, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class
        {
            var records = entities
                .Where(predicate)
                .ToList();
            if (records.Count > 0)
                entities.RemoveRange(records);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. This simulates the method `RemoveAll()` that's not available for DB sets of the entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove something you have a reference to. So you will have to search the entire list:

```
stuff r;
foreach(stuff s in prods) {
  if(s.ID == 1) {
      r = s;
      break;
  }
}
prods.Remove(r);
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < prods.Length; i++) {
    if(prods[i].ID == 1) {
        prods.RemoveAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't it faster to use the find or findIndex function on a list instead of looping through it?

Comment: You can't modify the collection you are iterating

Comment: @Rob, for a List, find should be the same.

Comment: @Graphain oops.
@Rob, yes a find is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

`prods.Remove(prods.Single(p=>p.ID == 1));`

you can't modify collection in foreach, as Vincent suggests

Comment: Single would be slower than first but it does guarantee you don't have duplicate products for the same ID which may be something you want to check for.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game, however, a simple extension method can implement a `RemoveAll` on `IList<T>`. The trick is to loop over the collection in reverse order to avoid the extra logic of deleting the current item and having to try on the current index if removed. Also the reverse order prevents having to copy all the remaining items. Depending on the .NET version, this copy could be expensive.

```cs
    public static int RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        if (match == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("match");

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (match(list[i]))
            {
                ++count;
                list.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use Linq.

```
var prod = from p in prods
           where p.ID != 1
           select p;
```

Comment: This won't remove the object. If you assign like `prods = prods.Where(p != 1).ToList()` you're closer, but that won't modify a list you've been given as a parameter.